# Images dont show in grid view, but do in list view

Tags: images, media-library

In media library, images show in list view, but not in grid view.  This becomes an issue because adding a featured image is done by grid view only.

I had to edit the DB to make all jpg files lower case, and changed the actual picture files to match.  Everything shows correctly except grid view.  New images I upload through media manager show fine in grid view.

[image: missing pics]

The corresponding URL is correct, as expected since the list view shows the image.  Plugins on or off do not make a difference.

Various forums have mentioned the same problem, but no solutions. What would be causing this and how to fix?

Comment: have you ever found a solution to this question? I have the same problem now.

Comment: Same issue here. Would love to find a fix.